# Cleanup Sitecore Assets Download Data

Tags: xdb, experience-analytics

I need to remove all the old Sitecore Analytics data related to Assets/Downloads.

I only need to remove these Assets related data from contacts/reports since there were some incorrect configuration of tracking events earlier.

I have look into Analytics Database Manager tool and it seems it doesn't have this option of only removing Assets related information.
https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Analytics_Database_Manager.aspx

Please let me know if there is a way we can achieve this.

Sitecore Version : 8.2

Comment: I would recommend to use repository in github of this module and add functionality that you need and then create pull request also for the others